# How to change the background for whole column and whole row of a selected cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

i have a jtable and i want when selecting a cell to change the background for the whole row and the whole column of this cell (not to change the background of the cell only !), how to do so ?

please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used the following to control color of a column.  To see how to incorporate the current cell, look at 
http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2001-09/03-qa-0928-jtable.html

```
    this.table = new JTable()
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -5739534894469353266L;


        /**
         * Set the background color of the row equal to the color of the path in the map
         */
        @Override
        public Component prepareRenderer( final TableCellRenderer renderer, final int Index_row, final int Index_col )
        {
            final Component comp = super.prepareRenderer( renderer, Index_row, Index_col );
            // even index, selected or not selected

            if ( Index_col == 1 )
            {
                // Color column, match foreground / background colors
                comp.setBackground( MyColors.getColor( Index_row ) );
                comp.setForeground( MyColors.getColor( Index_row ) );
            }
            else
            {
                comp.setBackground( Color.white );
                comp.setForeground( Color.black );
            }
            return comp;
        }
    };
```

Comment: what do you mean by the following ? `comp.setBackground( MyColors.getColor( Index_row ) );
                comp.setForeground( MyColors.getColor( Index_row ) );`

Comment: You would need to define class MyColors, and add a function getColor(int).  Or, replace MyColor.getColor( ... ) with an array like Color colors[] = { Color.black, Color.blue, Color.cyan, Color.darkGray, Color.gray, Color.green, Color.lightGray, Color.magenta, Color.orange, Color.pink, Color.red, Color.yellow };